# .vbs file not working properly from windows service

Tags: c++, vbscript, windows-services

I created a windows service in C++ which runs a VBScript file on a particular event. This works fine when I do this from a Win32 application in C++, but doesn't work the same way from windows service.

Code of CPP file:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ExecuteInfo;

memset(&ExecuteInfo, 0, sizeof(ExecuteInfo));

ExecuteInfo.cbSize       = sizeof(ExecuteInfo);
ExecuteInfo.fMask        = 0;                
ExecuteInfo.hwnd         = 0;                
ExecuteInfo.lpVerb       = _T("open");                      // Operation to perform
ExecuteInfo.lpFile       = _T("D:\\demo.vbs");  // Application name
ExecuteInfo.lpParameters = 0;           // Additional parameters
ExecuteInfo.lpDirectory  = 0;                           // Default directory
ExecuteInfo.nShow        = SW_SHOW;
ExecuteInfo.hInstApp     = 0;
if(ShellExecuteEx(&ExecuteInfo) == FALSE)
{
}
```

Comment: By default VBScripts are run with the "GUI" interpreter `wscript.exe`. Try running it with `cscript.exe`.

Comment: What "doesn't work the same way" does exactly mean?

Comment: @MC ND this line "Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows" gives all windows tab currently open from exe but when this's invoked from windows service that gives nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming objShell.Windows is an instance of "Shell.Application", what you get is according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> ShellWindows object: Represents a collection of the open windows that
>   belong to the Shell. Methods associated with this objects can control
>   and execute commands within the Shell, and obtain other Shell-related
>   objects.

The critical part is `that belong to the Shell`. Your problem is that the shell in your desktop is different from the shell that the services in your machine have.

Services run in a separate session.

So, your script is correctly working. It doesn't return any shell window because there is no one in the session where the services are running.

Comment: so how can i get this done? i want to get open windows of the user shell from the service? is there some to way do it?

Comment: In short NO. You can do it (see [here](http://developex.com/custom-software/devx-exec.html)), but the correct way of doing it is to detect user logon, and start a helper program running in the user session, and implement a way to make the helper program and the service communicate. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133375/Starting-Process-in-the-Logged-Session-under-the-L) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36581/Interaction-between-services-and-applications-at-u) you will find how (sorry, C/C++/C# code)

Answer (score 0):

I created a normal exe instead of windows service and added that to windows startup registory.
That way i was able to achieve desired.